Boost test: how to parametrize a test with input and output?
In Boost.Test, I'd like to test a function for different values, each value associated to an expected result.
Something like (I know, the test is stupid):
void SquareTest(int expectedResult, int input)
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expectedResult, MySquareFunctionToTest(input));
}

BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION_TEST_CASE(SquareTest,  4, 2);
BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION_TEST_CASE(SquareTest,  9, 3);
BOOST_AUTO_FUNCTION_TEST_CASE(SquareTest, 16, 4);

Is there a way to do that with Boost.Test ?
The parametrized section int the documentation doesn't seem to match to my need.

why do you want a macro for this? Instead of the macro why not just BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(4,MySquareFunctioNToTest(2)) and same for the other 2 cases

BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL() must be then inside a test case.

I would suggest the simple:
Live On Coliru
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

int MySquareFunctionToTest(int x) { return x * x; }

void SquareTest(int expectedResult, int input) {
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expectedResult, MySquareFunctionToTest(input));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SquareTest1) { SquareTest(4, 2); }
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SquareTest2) { SquareTest(9, 3); }
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SquareTest3) { SquareTest(16, 4); }

If you really feel like getting the Enterprise(TM) version on:
Data Driven Test Cases
These were added for very good rationale, that probably resonate with you, since you were asking this question:

The approach above has several drawbacks:

the logic for running the tests is inside a test itself: single_test in the above example is run from the test case
combined_test while its execution would be better handled by the Unit
Test Framework
in case of fatal failure for one of the values in param array above (say a failure in BOOST_TEST_REQUIRE), the test combined_test is
aborted and the next test-case in the test tree is executed.
in case of failure, the reporting is not accurate enough: the test should certainly be reran during debugging sessions by a human or
additional logic for reporting should be implemented in the test
itself.


(and much more)
Example:
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
namespace bdata = boost::unit_test::data;

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(SquareDataDrivenTest, bdata::make({2, 3, 4}), input) {
    SquareTest(input * input, input);
}

Of course, that's cheating. While
bdata::make({std::pair{2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}})

will work, it would require you to add printability to std::pair. To avoid that, consider:
struct Params {
    int a, a_squared;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Params& p){
        return os << "a=" << p.a << ", a_squared=" << p.a_squared;
    }
};

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(SquareDataDrivenTest2,                        //
                     bdata::make({Params{2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}}), //
                     input) {
    auto [a, a2] = input;
    SquareTest(a2, a);
}

Live On Coliru
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cbcc9f6bfb967b1
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test_parameters.hpp>

int MySquareFunctionToTest(int x) { return x * x; }

void SquareTest(int expectedResult, int input) {
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expectedResult, MySquareFunctionToTest(input));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SquareTest1) { SquareTest(4, 2); }
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SquareTest2) { SquareTest(9, 3); }
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(SquareTest3) { SquareTest(16, 4); }

// Now doing these with Data-Driven test cases:

#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
namespace bdata = boost::unit_test::data;

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(SquareDataDrivenTest, bdata::make({2, 3, 4}), input) {
    SquareTest(input * input, input);
}

struct Params {
    int a, a_squared;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Params& p){
        return os << "a=" << p.a << ", a_squared=" << p.a_squared;
    }
};

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(SquareDataDrivenTest2,                        //
                     bdata::make({Params{2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}}), //
                     input) {
    auto [a, a2] = input;
    SquareTest(a2, a);
}

Printing:
Running 9 test cases...

*** No errors detected

Or, -l all:
Running 9 test cases...
Entering test module "MyTest"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(11): Entering test case "SquareTest1"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(11): Leaving test case "SquareTest1"; testing time: 21us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(12): Entering test case "SquareTest2"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(12): Leaving test case "SquareTest2"; testing time: 18us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(13): Entering test case "SquareTest3"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(13): Leaving test case "SquareTest3"; testing time: 18us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(20): Entering test suite "SquareDataDrivenTest"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(20): Entering test case "_0"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    input = 2; 
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(20): Leaving test case "_0"; testing time: 20us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(20): Entering test case "_1"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    input = 3; 
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(20): Leaving test case "_1"; testing time: 18us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(20): Entering test case "_2"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    input = 4; 
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(20): Leaving test case "_2"; testing time: 17us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(20): Leaving test suite "SquareDataDrivenTest"; testing time: 62us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(32): Entering test suite "SquareDataDrivenTest2"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(32): Entering test case "_0"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    input = a=2, a_squared=4; 
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(32): Leaving test case "_0"; testing time: 19us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(32): Entering test case "_1"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    input = a=3, a_squared=9; 
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(32): Leaving test case "_1"; testing time: 18us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(32): Entering test case "_2"
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(8): info: check expectedResult == MySquareFunctionToTest(input) has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    input = a=4, a_squared=16; 
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(32): Leaving test case "_2"; testing time: 18us
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp(32): Leaving test suite "SquareDataDrivenTest2"; testing time: 60us
Leaving test module "MyTest"; testing time: 193us

*** No errors detected

Note how the data driven test cases report context with their invocations.

Thank you very much for the time you spent to write this answer.
For my need, I'm not convinced by data driven test cases. I was these ones more as a way to test several samples of data, byt my need is ore for nominal and limit values. Your final solution is pretty heavy, and you first proposal is probably better. I conclude there isn't really a clean way to satisfy my need.

@Oodini agreed. Limits deserve explicit cases, and data driven shines for cartesian products (combinatorial explosion of scenarios)
